# Starting a Process that calls a Console App on the Application Server from the Web Server.

Tags: c#, networking, server, console-application

I have a console application (on an application server) and a website (on web server). I have a button on the website that is used to call/ launch the console app. when I run the console app from the website the time taken is considerably slower than if I run the console app on the same server it is located . The only difference is that one call is over the network while the other is a local call. Is there anything I am doing wrong or can do to speed up the time to at least match the time it takes to run the Console App locally?

My code for the button on the website is as follows

```
protected void lbTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"\\servername\c$\ProjectFolder\ApplicationFiles\ConsoleApp.exe";


        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

        startInfo.Arguments = "/processname 23897203 M 36963";

        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(startInfo);

    }
```

Comment: What is the output in both cases? Could there be some errors happening when you're running it from the other server? Is it being run from an admin account or a regular account? These are things I would look at

Comment: Hi mikeyq6 , The output is the same in both cases since I supplied the same parameters in both instances. no errors as far as I am seeing. The user issue , you mean what user the website is being run under in iis or what user the console app uses to connect to the database? please explain

Comment: I mean, which user account is the process running under in both cases? If you run it directly on the application server, then you'd be running it as whichever account you are logged in as, but running it from the website would run it under whichever accoutn is listed in the application pool

Comment: Running on the server locally I logged in as me (I am listed as an administrator) I created a shortcut of the console app file, put in the parameters in the shortcut and then clicked run as administrator. on the website the user account on the application pool is an administrator on the server.

Comment: Start writing out to a log with the times, and compare logs for both scenarios, so that you can see if there is just a certain part of the application that is running slow.

Comment: I do have log files.
I'm trying to paste the 2 log files but they have too much characters.